# css or jquery on hover show only the hidden children element of current div

Tags: css

Following is the html structure, that is repeating inside my html page.

```
<article class="tweet-inner"> 
    <div class="tweet">
        <div class="text">
            <p>Coming down! Time for Croation BBQ </p>
        </div>

        <p class="last"> 
            <span class="pull-right">
                <small> Hello this is first text </small>
                <small> Hello this is second text </small>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</article>
```

The above is one unit of repeating structure inside my HTML.

The functionality I want is, when you hover over the tweet text, `.tweet .text p` then the content of `.last` should show.

I did the following :

```
.last{
    display: none;
}

.tweet .text p:hover .last{
    display: block;
}
```

Two doubts :

1. You should be able to see the `.last` of only the element upon which you have hovered.
2. The above is not working, the fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/EymLT/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS selector is incorrect. Firstly `.last` is not a child of `.text`, and the `p` element cannot be hovered because it is invisble. Try this:

```
.tweet:hover .last{
    display : block;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EymLT/1/)

Comment: the trouble is if I am hovering on any one of the <article> elements, all the `.last` elements are showing up. not here in the fiddle but in the html.

Comment: @user1629366 are you sure you've copied my code correctly, as that doesn't happen in my example fiddle with 2 `article` elements

Comment: It also shouldn't be possible for that to happen, as the CSS is selecting the `.last` as a child of the hovered element. Do you have some javascript lingering somewhere?

Comment: added another div on top of `.tweet` and wrote hover on it, started working. donnno, why :P

Answer (score 0):

Replace your last style with this:

```
.tweet .text:hover + .last{
    display : block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `~` in CSS

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/EymLT/4/

```
.last{
    display:none;
}

.text:hover ~ .last{
    display : block;
}
```

If you replace my `~` with `>` it will be more browser compatable. The `>` ensures only the child is seleted so you can use a parent div as the hover target.

```
.last{
    display:none;
}

.tweet:hover > .last{
    display : block;
}
```

Comment: the trouble with this approach is that, I have some actionable items, in `.last` when I take mouse away from `.text` the element disappers.

Comment: You want the element visible on hover, do you want it to remain visible too?